# In a new job; is it OK to recommend a partner for a job search?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, job-search, two-body-problem

I just started a new job teaching at a university last September; because of that, I’m also in a long-distance relationship. (We’re not married or even engaged at this point.) My partner is also in my field and has applied for a job in my department which would start this September. My question is: is it out-of-line for me to contact one of my colleagues on the hiring committee, explain the situation, and ask about the status of my partner’s application? Obviously, since I am a brand new hire, I don’t want to be overstepping my bounds here, and I’m unsure if I have any real “say” in the matter to begin with.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: While not directly inquiring or influencing the possible hire, if you _want_ to mention your "two-body problem" to your dept chair, they can do whatever seems appropriate in your local context with local policies, local rules, etc.

Comment: The question in the title seems rather different from the question in the body of the text. Recommending someone does not generally entail pressuring the hiring manager!

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: is it out-of-line for me to contact one of my colleagues on the hiring committee, explain the situation, and ask about the status of my partner’s application?

**This is definitely out-of-line** --- any contact with the hiring committee to attempt to influence them in favour of hiring your partner is contrary to the assurances that universities make to applicants to hire on merit.  If you do this, you will rightly be seen as attempting to influence the hiring process based on considerations where you have a personal interest.  Secondarily, the hiring committee probably has no *right* to give any information to you on the status of any person's application, since you are not part of the hiring process (and if you were, you would need to declare a conflict of interest).

I would strongly recommend you don't raise this at all, particularly if you are a new staff member.  Depending on the particular rules of your institution, there is a possibility that this could be considered a breach of university rules, or even a form of employee misconduct, which is not a good start to your position.  Please bear a thought for the other applicants for the position, who are not dating an academic in your department.  These people want fair consideration on their merits, without any "whispers in the ear" of the hiring committee.

Comment: In the EU, providing such information to someone not involved in the hiring process would almost certainly breach GDPR legislation.

Answer (score 2):

Almost everywhere the proper response to such a question would be "no comment." It is improper for a potential employer to comment on an applicant to anyone not part of the hiring process. So, I strongly recommend that you don't ask. It will probably be an embarrassment and might be seen as interference.

Giving a recommendation, however, is a slightly different matter, as long as you reveal the relationship. But whoever is responsible for hiring might have to disregard any such recommendation unless you make it formally as part of the process.

But even a proper recommendation is problematic, since your opinion won't be considered independent. Your partner would do best to use independent recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in informing the hiring committee that your significant other is applying. Even better if you can do so informally (and it is better coming from you than from your partner).

Most academics can relate to the plights of the 2-body problem, and resolving it for its employees benefits the department (e.g. it increases the chances of retaining you, and an employee not dealing with the 2-body problem is likely to be more productive.)

The hiring committee may or may not take this in consideration, but it is unlikely to be held against you or your partner. You can, of course, tell them what you think of your partner's academic qualifications, but be prepared to be taken with a grain of salt.